# Mechanical heart in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What would be the correct translation of "mechanical heart" as in sense of a core, something thanks to what a system runs? I was told "cor mechanicum", but I'd like to double-check it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of the introduction to Hobbes' *Leviathan*. Though *Leviathan* was originally published in English in 1651, he produced a revised Latin edition in 1668. Here are the first lines of the intro:

> NATURAM, id est, illam qua mundum Deus condidit et gubernat, divinam artem, eatenus imitatur ars humana, ut possit inter alia producere **artificiale animal**. Cum enim vita nihil aliud sit quam artuum motus, cujus principium est internum in parte aliqua corporis principali, quid obstat quo minus dicamus automata omnia, sive machinas omnes quae ab elastris rotulisque intus dispositis motum habent, ut horologia, in seipsis, habere etiam artificialem vitam? **Quid est cor nisi elastrum**, quid nervi nisi chordae, quid articuli nisi totidem rotulae motum, qualem voluit artifex, toti corpori impertientes?

Here's the original English version of the same intro:

> Nature (the art whereby God hath made and governes the world) is by the
> art of man, as in many other things, so in this also imitated, that it
> can make an **Artificial Animal**. For seeing life is but a motion of Limbs,
> the begining whereof is in some principall part within; why may we not
> say, that all Automata (Engines that move themselves by springs and
> wheeles as doth a watch) have an artificiall life? For **what is the
> Heart, but a Spring**; and the Nerves, but so many Strings; and the
> Joynts, but so many Wheeles, giving motion to the whole Body, such as
> was intended by the Artificer?

My suggestion, based on this, is **cor artificiale**, though the passage gives many other possible words to explore, e.g. *automaton*, *machina*, etc.

In this context, "artificial" is contrasted with "natural."